# Unable to download files from firebase through pyrebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am stuck with it for a long time now, must be something silly!!!

I have this simple code that uses pyrebase to connect to Firebase:

```
db = firebase.database()
auth = firebase.auth()
storage = firebase.storage()
user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password('user','pwd')

tok = user['idToken']

try:
    files = db.child("files").get(tok)
    l = []
    for f in files.each():
        l = f.val()
        print(l)
        storage.child(l).download(l,token=tok)
        # url = storage.child(l).get_url(tok)  -----This line gets the proper URL
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I am getting data correctly accessed from DB, but the download task does nothing. I have no idea what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:**
as per suggestion:

Database structure:

```
{
  "files" : {
    "-L2vvsSL3l95QZqMILRb" : "car_WIFI_6cf4d4f1-4bfe-488b-b671-d0f816cd5e65.txt",
    "-L2vvsSScNqiUZ-HYTM1" : "car_GPS_6cf4d4f1-4bfe-488b-b671-d0f816cd5e65.txt"
  }
}
```

And storage structure:

[image: Data Storage Screenshot]

Comment: Can you post your database and storage structures?

Comment: Ya sure, files are directly saved in the root of the storage. same file names are kept in 'files' in database as it is required to get all the uploaded files at once.

Comment: I'm sorry, I might have expressed that wrong. I meant: can you shows us how your Firebase database and Firebase storage are structured? It will be easier for us to help you if we can see your JSON tree.

Comment: I went through their(pyrebase) issue logs, it is mentioned that usage of service account is recommended. But its not mentioned to be mandatory. Is that a issue?

Comment: Not sure how I can share that, screenshots won't help i guess?

Comment: You can find an "Export JSON" button in your [Firebase Database Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data) to export the Database. You can post a screenshot of the firebase storage tree.

Comment: Thanks, linking it to the question. However it is working with a storage account. Guessing it is a limitation.

Comment: Just checked the structures. Everything looks correct... You mentioned adding a service account credential as a recommendation from their issue logs. I believe that's worth a shot. Can you try and do that?

Comment: I did try that and it is working with the service account. I added a comment in that discussion as well to confirm this behavior. Keeping this post for now in case any proper solution is found.

Comment: Glad to know that it works! I'll post my answer anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue on Pyrebase's GitHub](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/48), you need to [add a service account credential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup#prerequisites) in order to download storage files. That allows Pyrebase to authenticate with Firebase as an admin and disregard any security rules.